# Notions of "completeness" and "sufficiency" of a mathematical model

Tags: terminology, applied-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

I'm modelling a real-world problem as having instances $i$ in a set $P$. As a very simple artificial example, consider the problem of choosing a meeting room given a certain number of people. Then $i = 2$ represents a problem instance of finding a meeting room for 2 people. Let's put $P = \mathbb{Z}$ for the sake of example, even though we have better options like $\mathbb{Z_0^+}$.

I define certain restrictions $A$ on $P$ using logical formulae over structure of $i$. e.g. I can say $\forall i \in P,~i > -10$ , i.e. any problem in the problem domain, if represented using $i \in P$ would satisfy $A$. Let $P$ under $A$ be $P' =  \{p : p \in P \land p~\text{satisfies}~A\}$.

But it's possible that $\exists i' \in P'$ such that $i'$ is a valid mathematical structure but doesn't actually correspond to valid any real-world problem (e.g. $-5 \in P'$).

What is the standard terminology to say

1. All valid problem instances are a part of $P'$ (I'm informally calling this "sufficiency")
2. All problem instances which are a part of $P'$ are valid (I'm informally calling this "completeness")

I may then use this terminology to say that in my example, $P'$ is *sufficient* but *incomplete* (replacing these two words with the actual terminology)

---

Because I'm looking for terminology which is domain-independent, I'll give another example. Let's model valid sudoku problem instances (where I define "valid" as having a unique solution) using $P = \{\_, 1, \ldots, 9\}^{9*9}$ where "_" represents a blank and numbers start from top left cell, go towards right and then down.

Let $A$ be the condition that all rows, columns, and boxes have unique numbers (disregarding the blanks).

Here also you can specify all valid problem instances as members of $P$, but $P$ might include some invalid problem instances too (those with multiple or no solutions). It's possible to make the condition $A$ stronger to get rid of invalid instances, and that's precisely one of the reasons I need terminology to distinguish between that and the $A$ I've currently given.

Comment: Not a main part of the question, but additionally I'd also like to know if there are terms to say "each problem is uniquely represented", and "each representation corresponds to a unique problem".

Comment: The model is relevant; in particular, without some examples of $i$ or $A$ or how you use this model, it’s difficult to say anything about this at all.

Comment: Then I'll have to create some artificial examples to explain. I'll do that, and in the meanwhile if anyone can answer without that, feel free to go ahead.

Comment: I don’t know what fits your situation, but in most contexts, *necessary* is paired with *sufficient*, while *complete* is paired with *sound*.

Comment: This is more of an applied-mathematics question than a logic question. "Complete" in mathematical logic means something quite different than what I think you are asking: something like, say you label each person in a city with their gender, birthdate, and shoe size.  Do those 3 coordinates enough to uniquely label every person?  Can every person be labelled, e.g. could your city have amputees with no feet,so no valid shoe size?  I'd just use plain English for this sort of thing: there's no mathematical terms that I can think of.  The application area might have its own terminology though.

Comment: I've updated the question with a simple example. I'd have thought that there would be application-agnostic terms to describe this, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: @none I also disagree with your tag choices, since for instance many theories have a formal foundation (e.g. automata theory, game theory) which I think aren't considered applied mathematics.  I couldn't find a tag for formalization so I instead chose some elementary tools used in formalization: logic and set theory. But I won't roll back since the edit was approved.